# Slack message JSON, image not showing

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm building a simple Slack integration. I've got a web app running on a public URL that is returning json like so when my slash command is called:

```
{

"text": "<http://lorempixel.com/image_output/animals-q-c-640-480-4.jpg>"

}
```

If I paste that [JSON in to their format testing tool](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Florempixel.com%2Fimage_output%2Fanimals-q-c-640-480-4.jpg%3E%22%7D), it shows the image as expected. But, when I actually test the slash command in Slack, where my web app returns the exact same JSON, Slack shows the image url as a link, but doesn't show the image.

Thoughts?

Comment: From reading some of the docs, it looks like "URL detection is performed by the server", so it's possible user messages are handled differently from slash command responses. https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting. Also, https://api.slack.com/docs/attachments gives an overview of attaching things to your messages. Maybe try that format.

Comment: Although it really does look like that message builder should validate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried `"response_type": "in_channel"`? I have a suspicion that ephemeral messages simply don't get their links unfurled.

Comment: Try setting `unfurl_links` to `true` https://api.slack.com/docs/unfurling

Comment: @PetrGazarov Well, I think you'd want `unfurl_media`, but both default to `true` anyway.

Comment: @smarx from docs: `For messages posted via webhooks or the chat.postMessage API method, we will unfurl links to media, but not other links.` so I thought it was worth a try

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried all of the above, to know avail. It's frustrating that something so simple is not working. We don't have a paid account, so maybe there's some limitation for custom integrations? Although images show up for other integrations...ugh.

Comment: @Scott You're saying you tried `"response_type":  "in_channel"` and the link still wasn't unfurled? I tried the exact image you're using above, and it definitely displayed when I used an in-channel message. Also a free account.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with having the image in the text AND attachment:

```
{
  "parse": "full",
  "response_type": "in_channel",
  "text": "<http://lorempixel.com/image_output/animals-q-c-640-480-4.jpg>",
  "attachments": [
    {
        "image_url": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/animals-q-c-640-480-4.jpg"
    }
   ],
   "unfurl_media": true,
   "unfurl_links": true

 }
```

This doesn't appear to jive with the documentation and other examples I've seen, but at least it's working now!

Comment: FWIW, `"response_type": "in_channel"` is all I needed to get this exact example to work.

Comment: Also just in addition to this: If you post a link (or an integration posts a link) to a channel more than once in a certain time period, it will only be unfurled **once**. You will have to wait a set amount of time before another posting of this link will lead to another unfurl.